# Calculate portfolio value growth in Python/Pandas/Django

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
                YAR.OL     NHY.OL  ...      DNB.OL     SBO.OL
date                               ...                       
1986-03-13         NaN        NaN  ...         NaN        NaN
1986-03-14         NaN        NaN  ...         NaN        NaN
1986-03-17         NaN        NaN  ...         NaN        NaN
1986-03-18         NaN        NaN  ...         NaN        NaN
1986-03-19         NaN        NaN  ...         NaN        NaN
...                ...        ...  ...         ...        ...
2020-07-24  377.799988  26.740000  ...  144.500000  51.000000
2020-07-27  381.799988  26.350000  ...  142.199997  50.599998
2020-07-28  382.399994  26.490000  ...  142.000000  50.200001
2020-07-29  377.899994  26.389999  ...  142.100006  50.799999
2020-07-30  372.000000  25.049999  ...  137.149994  49.799999
```

And these lists containing trade information:

```
ticker_list = ['YAR.OL', 'NHY.OL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT', 'STB.OL', 'DNB.OL', 'SBO.OL']
transaction_price_list = [100.0, 21.0, 1850.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 40.0]
transaction_date_list = [datetime.date(2020, 6, 17), datetime.date(2020, 5, 12), datetime.date(2020, 6, 9), datetime.date(2020, 7, 23), dt.datetime.date(2020, 3, 11), dt.datetime.date(2002, 2, 13), dt.datetime.date(2020, 2, 18)]
trade_volum_list = [10, 194, 10, 10, 10, 100, 10]
```

I'm trying to create a new dataframe that will show the growth of the portfolio given the trades that have been taken place on different dates.

My code looks like this:

```
def portfolio_growth(self, ticker_list, transaction_price_list, transaction_date_list, trade_volum_list):

    df = self.dataset_creator(ticker_list)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    
    for ticker, price, dates, volume in zip(ticker_list, transaction_price_list, transaction_date_list, trade_volum_list):

        first_date_to_str = str(dates)
        first_date_to_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(first_date_to_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
        first_date_to_date = first_date_to_dt.date()

        s = df[ticker]

        new_df[ticker] = s.loc[first_date_to_date::] * volume
        new_df[first_date_to_date,ticker] = price * volume

    first_date = min(transaction_date_list)
    sum_df = new_df.sum(axis=1)
    sum_df = sum_df.loc[first_date::]
    portfolio_df = pd.DataFrame(index=sum_df.index)
    portfolio_df['Portfolio_Value'] = sum_df


    return portfolio_df
```

However I'm not able to calculate this correctly. When I print out the portfolio_df I get this dataframe in return.

```
            Portfolio_Value
date                       
2002-02-13     39952.730011
2002-02-14     40076.180099
2002-02-15     40076.180099
2002-02-19     40057.179855
2002-02-20     40095.170044
...                     ...
2020-07-24     76590.759861
2020-07-27     77568.399464
2020-07-28     76927.159840
2020-07-29     77127.960266
2020-07-30     76285.898682
```

On 2002-02-13 the portfolio value should be 1000 due to I buy 10 MSFT @ 100 each. And the same mistake continue throughout the method.

I have managed to do this in excel:
[image: Calculations done in excel]

How can I write this code in Python? And how would it work if there be a sell order aswell?

I know this might be a lot, I really appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks :)

---

Reducing the example to 2 stocks and 5 days.

```
                YAR.OL     NHY.OL  
date                                                      
2020-07-24  377.799988  26.740000 
2020-07-27  381.799988  26.350000 
2020-07-28  382.399994  26.490000  
2020-07-29  377.899994  26.389999  
2020-07-30  372.000000  25.049999
```

Trade lists:

```
ticker_list = ['YAR.OL', 'NHY.OL']
transaction_price_list = [370, 26]
transaction_date_list = [datetime.date(2020, 7, 24), datetime.date(2020, 7, 28)]
trade_volum_list = [10, 15]
```

Comment: Can you reduce it to one/two stocks and to 2 or 3 days example?

Comment: @user1700890 I have added a new example with 2 stocks and 5 days. :)

Comment: So if we compute manually, the value of your portfolio 7/24 ~ $3,778 ; 7/27 ~ $3,818; 7/28 ~ $4,221.35. Is this what you expect?

Comment: @user1700890 No, the portfolio value would be 7/24 - 3700 (Volume * Trade price)(10 * 370) | 7/27 - 3817,99 (Volume * market price) ( 10 * 381,799) | 7/28 4214 (Volume * market price for trade 1) + (Volume * trade price)... ect
The data that comes in is dynamic, so need to create a logic for this so it will calculate this automatic

Comment: Seems to be fair, what are you going to do if you partially sell a stock? For example on 7/30 you sold 5 shares of YAR.OL for $350

Comment: If you sold then it would be subtracted from the initial volume. So you had 10 now you have 5. The five you would would be added to a new df of realized positions. Example: 7/30 -  ( Initial Volume - sold volume * mkt price) <-- This is the value in the market. And the realized value would be 7/30 (Volume sold * Price sold) @user1700890

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219286/discussion-between-waleed-ahmed-and-user1700890).

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion, here is my solution. Not too elegant, but seems to be working:

Here is your data:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import numpy as np


    price_df = pd.DataFrame({'price_date': [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25) ,
                                     datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27), 
                                    datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 29), 
                            datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 30)], 'A' : np.linspace(1,100, 7), 
                            'B' : np.linspace(100,200, 7)})
    
    
    ticker_list = ['A', 'B', 'A']
    transaction_price_list  = [10,15, 70 ]
    transaction_date_list = [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24),
                             datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28), 
                            datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 30)]
    trade_volum_list = [10, 15, -5]
```

Some transformations:

```
    trade_df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':ticker_list,
                             'transact_price': transaction_price_list, 
                             'transact_date':transaction_date_list,
                            'trade_vol' : trade_volum_list})


    
    trade_df['purchase_indicator'] = trade_df.trade_vol/abs(trade_df.trade_vol)
    trade_df.loc[trade_df.purchase_indicator == -1, 'purchase_indicator'] =0
    
    
    final_df = pd.DataFrame(price_df.price_date)
    final_df['port_value'] = 0
    for el_ticker in set(ticker_list):
        temp_df_1 = trade_df.loc[trade_df.ticker == el_ticker, ]
        temp_df_2 = pd.merge(price_df[['price_date', el_ticker]],  temp_df_1, how = 'left',
               left_on='price_date', right_on='transact_date')
        
        temp_df_2.trade_vol.fillna(0, inplace= True)
        temp_df_2.purchase_indicator.fillna(0, inplace= True)
        temp_df_2.transact_price.fillna(0, inplace= True)
        
        temp_df_2['shares'] = temp_df_2.trade_vol.cumsum()
        temp_df_2['price_choice'] = (temp_df_2.purchase_indicator) * temp_df_2.transact_price + (1- temp_df_2.purchase_indicator) * temp_df_2[el_ticker]
        temp_df_2['value']  = temp_df_2.price_choice * temp_df_2.shares
    
        final_df.port_value = final_df.port_value + temp_df_2.value
    
    final_df


price_date  port_value
0   2020-07-24  100.0
1   2020-07-25  175.0
2   2020-07-26  340.0
3   2020-07-27  505.0
4   2020-07-28  895.0
5   2020-07-29  3585.0
6   2020-07-30  3500.0
```